# Configuring a font variant in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to force IntelliJ to use a specific font variant, *e.g.* `Source Code Pro Light`? As far as I know, IntelliJ always assume the **regular** variant, and doesn't allow one to specify **what** to be used as bold and italic.

---

I have probably not been clear. There is a way to select a fixed variant (bold and italic), but IntelliJ decides what that variant should be. As an example, consider the fact I want to configure IntelliJ to use the following fonts:

- Normal Text -> Source Code Pro **Light** (and not Regular)
- Bold -> Source Code Pro **Regular** (and not Bold)
- Italic -> Source Code Pro Powerline **Italic** (not the same font)

Comment: Maybe create your own variant of font like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508/how-to-modify-the-style-property-of-a-font-on-windows

Comment: Leaving a comment since this is actually the exact same scenario (and font) I want to use!  Lets hope it gets added to intellj (and the rest of the platform) sometime in the next 10 years.

Comment: If Mac, remove other font variants in the Font Book app. I left only light, restarted IDEA. Working.

Comment: I am just here to say I have the exact same problem. Every proposed solution is a hack, so far, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac, you can remove (or disable) other font variants in the Font Book app. I left only `Fira Code Light`, restarted IDEA and got it working.
A not ideal solution, but at least the fonts are now thin together with subpixel antialiasing.
I have found related issues on IDEA's youtrack:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109338
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164392
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92825

Please vote :)

Answer (score -2):

Go to

*settings ->IDE Settings ->Editor -> Color and Fonts ->Then you will find `Schema Name` just click save as type a name(**Doing this will not change your default schema settings**) -> Then start manipulating the sub-menu of `Color and Fonts`*

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Dont think intellij allows that